# What is the correct way to do many to many entity relation insert?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using .net5 and EntityFrameworkCore 5.

I have a many to many relationship between Questions and Categories.

I am using Code first generation.

```cs
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to know how to add a Question with Categories.

I tried this :

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Question>> PostQuestion(Question question)
{
    question.Categories.Add(new Category() { Id = 1 });
    _context.Questions.Add(question);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtAction("GetQuestion", new { id = question.Id }, question);
}
```

And I have a Category with the Id : 1 in my database.

However I get this exception

`SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

What is the correct way to do many to many entity relation insert ?

Comment: This error is indicating that you're specifying an id for an identity friend - try eliminating the id =1 there and see how it works.

Comment: @KeithNicholas But if a Question can have multiple categories and if I do not want to duplicate the categories I need to have a many to many relationship. I am wrong ?

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens But then how can I link the question to a certain Category ?

Comment: You would capture the resulting Id as the result of the save command. Give it a try and update the question if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truly correct and intended way is to load the related entities into context before adding them to the "links" collection.

Let say you have a list of existing related entity keys:

```
var categoryIds = new[] { 1, 3, 4 };
```

Then you can use the `Find` method to load the corresponding entities into context and obtain their instances:

```
question.Categories = categoryIds
    .Select(id => _context.Categories.Find(id))
    .ToList();
```

The drawback is that it makes `N` database roundtrips to load the data you might not really need.

It can be made with just one additional database roundtrip by issuing `Contains` based query instead:

```
question.Categories = await _context.Categories
    .Where(e => categoryIds.Contains(e.Id))
    .ToListAsync();
```

If you really don't want the related entities, following are some other ways.

If the context lifetime is scoped to just that call, then you can use fake (stub) entities as with your attempt, but you have to `Attach` them to the context to let EF Core treat them as existing rather than as new if you don't do that:

```
question.Categories = categoryIds
    .Select(id => _context.Attach(new Category { Id = id }))
    .ToList();
```

Another way is to insert directly entries in the shadow join dictionary type entity set. But it requires knowing the conventional names of the join entity type and its shadow FKs, so this is type unsafe.

Also you need to first to `Add` the entity in order to have its temporary key available:

```
var entry = _context.Questions.Add(question);
```

Then for the shown model you have

```
var joinEntityName = "CategoryQuestion";
var fromPK = nameof(Question.Id);
var fromFK = "QuestionsId";
var toFK = "CategoriesId";
```

Actually these can be obtained from the EF Core metadata, which would make it safer:

```
var navInfo = entry.Collection(e => e.Courses).Metadata as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ISkipNavigation;
var joinEntityName = navInfo.JoinEntityType.Name;
var fromPK = navInfo.ForeignKey.PrincipalKey.Properties.Single().Name;
var fromFK = navInfo.ForeignKey.Properties.Single().Name;
var toFK = navInfo.Inverse.ForeignKey.Properties.Single().Name;
```

Then the insert code is:

```cs
var fromId = entry.CurrentValues[fromPK]; // the temp PK
db.Set<Dictionary<string, object>>(joinEntityName).AddRange(
    categoryIds.Select(toId => new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { fromFK, fromId },
        { toFK, toId },
    }));
```